# Migrate GitHub repo files to Azure DevOps Wikis from different project

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I have a repository in GitHub and have a bunch of documentation(.md) files there.
I want to migrate the documentations into one of the Azure DevOps Wikis.
I am referring [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#publish-a-git-repository-to-a-wiki-1) link.
When I am using the option ***Publish code as Wiki***,it only shows the repositories which are available inside the Azure DevOps project.
Is there a way I can publish the GitHub documentations in repositories which are from another project into the Azure DevOps Wikis?

Comment: Please consider adding the `azure-devops-wiki` tag. I would do it but, `Suggested edit queue is full`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider approaching this differently. If you are using git for your Azure DevOps project, then the Azure DevOps Wiki should be persisted to a hidden, but locatable, git repository. Git clone the source and target repositories locally. Then copy what you want to the target (Azure DevOps Wiki, local clone). Git add, commit, and push the added target files.

Attached images/files, if any, may be more problematic depending on how exactly they are represented in the source GitHub repo. In Azure DevOps Wiki ALL attachments are simply stored in a root `.attachments` folder. So, you'll need to migrate them there and "fix up" your links.

I've done this going the other direction, Azure DevOps Wiki -> GitHub Enterprise repo. You should know that you’ll likely need to “fix up” page links and that the two markdown styles have slight variations you may have to address.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can publish the GitHub documentations into the Azure DevOps Wikis?

- *for copying documents from GitHub you need to use Import repository from your devops project.*

> how to import an existing Git repo from GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, or other location into a new or empty existing repo in your Azure DevOps project.

[image]

[image]

- *For complete information you can go through the Import Git repo [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops).*

Comment: Actually, I do not want to import the complete repository. Instead the .md files from GitHub need to be migrated to an existing repository's Wiki.

Comment: in the same link you even have info regarding importing to existing repository but  even that is also for complete repository will provide the info of your ask once we perform locally